# How to compile text file to exe file with G++

Tags: compile, g++

I have c++ code saved in .txt file. Can i somehow format it with g++ compiler or i\ must change it to file.cpp?
Is there why how to compile a .txt file with g++?
Thanks for answare.

Comment: I doubt it will work, but try and see: `g++ -c file.txt`.

Comment: Hi @harrymc I tried it but it show an error:\
g++: warning: Skus.txt: linker input file unused because linking not done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [g++ man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/g++.1.html):

```
You can specify the input language explicitly with the -x option:

   -x language
       Specify explicitly the language for the following input files
       (rather than letting the compiler choose a default based on
       the file name suffix).  This option applies to all following
       input files until the next -x option.  Possible values for
       language are:

               c  c-header  cpp-output
               c++  c++-header  c++-cpp-output
               objective-c  objective-c-header  objective-c-cpp-output
               objective-c++ objective-c++-header objective-c++-cpp-output
               assembler  assembler-with-cpp
               ada
               d
               f77  f77-cpp-input f95  f95-cpp-input
               go
               brig
```

So, doing `g++ -x c++ file.txt` should work.